Is it possible to make MudExRichTextEdit textarea (editor) bigger/grow in terms of our need?
I am using MudExRichTextEdit package in my Company's project, and as a new developer I always want to ask, and have to ask If I am in a dire situation.
Currently with this rich text editor, I am not finding anywhere the possibility to make this rich editor grow in terms of our need, in terms of how much text it contains, or even screenshots/photos. Currently we can only do that by giving the editor a base min-height, but it doesn't auto grow.
It only gives the possibility of a scroll option inside the editor, but that does not work with what we need to accomplish.
We also want to print the form page we have created, and it doesn't show the whole picture/text inside the editor.
Has anyone had issues of this kind?
The rich editor implementation looks like this :
<MudExRichTextEdit For="@(() => Model!.CurrentState)"
                   Value="@Model!.CurrentState"                    
                   Immediate="true"                    
                   Height="300"                   
                   Placeholder="">
</MudExRichTextEdit>

I would gladly appreciate the help!

To solve your issue you can style the .ql-container class and remove the Height property from the MudExRichTextEdit component.

And the css that you need so that it grows, set the min-height and max-height
<style>
    .ql-container {
        min-height:20px;
        max-height:600px;
    }
</style>

<MudExRichTextEdit @ref="_editor" 
                   Modules="@_modules"
                   ReadOnly="@_readOnly"
                   Immediate="@_updateValueOnChange"
                   EnableResize="true"
                   CustomUploadFunc="OnUpload"
                   Files="@_files"
                   Class="m-2"
                   @bind-Value="@_value"
                   Placeholder="Write here">
</MudExRichTextEdit>

Demo


FYI this is an extension component and wasn't created by MudBlazor team.
https://github.com/fgilde/MudExRichTextEditor

Thank you for the help.
Like you said it only came out to be the Height variable.
Used min and max height css styles and now it works.
Thank you!
I wanted to ask if you have any idea why the link part of the tooltips in the mudexrichtextedit´s tooldbar is not working?

I'll have a look when I get back to my pc but I suggest you open an issue on the the components github https://github.com/fgilde/MudExRichTextEditor

@AnduelKaramani the link seems to be working, I used the example in the repo. You need to select the text then click on the link button.

yeah that I could do myself too, I wanted to change that feature into a more understandable one for the user.
I find it disturbing needing to enter the text, then select it in order to change it to a link, where the pop up link window could have been shown directly onclick.
Thank you though!
